# Cómo puedo verificar en TODAS mis tablas al mismo tiempo si algún registro es NULL ? estoy usando SQLite

Tags: sql

Quiero verificar en una sentencia si alguna de mis tablas tiene valores NULL, sé que puedo hacer:

```
SELECT*
FROM user
WHERE id IS NULL
```

Pero eso sólo me mostrará esa columna, la idea es todas de una.
¿Alguna idea?
¿Si es posible?
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La forma natural en SQL es construir la sentencia contemplando cada columna: `WHERE id IS NUL OR col1 IS NUL OR ...` , no hay otra forma. Lo que eventualmente podrías , es construir una sentencia dinámica, pero esto depende del motor de base de datos que uses, que por cierto deberías indicar en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Deseas saber si en una tabla tienes alguna fila con valor NULL en cualquier columna de esta? Creo que el título de la pregunta y la descripción son un poco ambiguas. También sería valioso agregar que motor de base de datos está utilizando.

Comment: Si, quiero ver en todas las tablas con un mismo select, verificar si en alguna columna hay valores null.

Comment: Es que si realizo un OR no va a estar del todo bien, pues si encuentra por ejemplo NULL en la columna4 no me va a verificar las columnas que le siguen.